# URI Syntax error when getting AppData path in java

Tags: java, uri

I am trying to get the path for the `AppData` folder by using this code:

```
URI myuri = new URI(System.getenv("AppData")+"custom file name etc...");
```

When I run the code I get this error:

> java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2:
>   C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\custom file name etc...

I think the problem is the the colon right after the *C* so I thought I should remove it and tried doing this:

```
String appdata_path = System.getenv("AppData");
appdata_path.replace(":", "");
URI myuri = new URI(appdata_path+"custom file name etc...");
```

But the result remains the same and I get the same error.
What is the correct way to get a path for the `AppData` folder and use it in a `URI`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read up on [what a URI actually is](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html).  A file name is *not* a valid URI.

You can convert a file name to a URI with the [Path.toUri](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#toUri--) method:

```
URI myuri = Paths.get(System.getenv("AppData"), "dir1", "dir2", "config.xml").toUri();
```